# How get number of subfolders and folders using Python os walks?

Tags: python

What I have a directory of folders and subfolders. What I'm trying to do is get the number of subfolders within the folders, and plot them on a scatter plot using matplotlib. I have the code to get the number of files, but how would I get the number of subfolders within a folder. This probably has a simple answer but I'm a newb to Python. Any help is appreciated.

This is the code I have so far to get the number of files:

```
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def fcount(path):
    count1 = 0
    for f in os.listdir(path):
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, f)):
            count1 += 1

    return count1

path = "/Desktop/lay"
print fcount(path)
```

Comment: You increment a var named `count1` and you return another one named `count` (and not defined)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
import os

def fcount(path, map = {}):
  count = 0
  for f in os.listdir(path):
    child = os.path.join(path, f)
    if os.path.isdir(child):
      child_count = fcount(child, map)
      count += child_count + 1 # unless include self
  map[path] = count
  return count

path = "/Desktop/lay"
map = {}
print fcount(path, map)
```

Here is a full implementation and tested. It returns the number of subfolders without the current folder. If you want to change that you have to put the + 1 in the last line instead of where the comment is.

Answer (score 5):

I think os.walk could be what you are looking for:

```
import os

def fcount(path):
    count1 = 0
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
            count1 += len(dirs)

    return count1

path = "/home/"
print fcount(path)
```

This will walk give you the number of directories in the given path.

Comment: `count1 += len(dirs)` would be more effective. And aren't you shadowing the `path` variable?

Comment: @Danyel Ok I get actually understand this one. If I wanted to plot the number of subfolders in each folder on a graph. How would I go about doing it.

Comment: I posted an answer that does exactly that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19748014/1527244

Answer (score 4):

Try the following recipe:

```
import os.path  
import glob  
folder = glob.glob("path/*")
len(folder)
```

Answer (score 3):

Answering to:

> how would I get the number of subfolders within a folder

You can use the `os.path.isdir` function similarly to `os.path.isfile` to count directories.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for `os.walk`. Look in the Python reference, it says that:

> `os.walk(top, topdown=True, onerror=None, followlinks=False)`
>
> Generate the file names in a directory tree by walking the tree either top-down
>   or bottom-up. For each directory in the tree rooted at directory top
>   (including top itself), it yields a 3-tuple (`dirpath, dirnames,
>   filenames`).

So, you can try to do this to get only the directories:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/usr/bin'):
    for name in dirs:
        print os.path.join(root, name)
        count += 1
```